# Not able to import Quartz Monitor plugin in Grails 2.4.3

Tags: maven, grails, grails-plugin

I have installed quartz plugin for my grails project and have created Job.

BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugin {
  compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
}
```

now i want to have the following plugin to monitor the jobs i have created.

https://grails.org/plugin/quartz-monitor

For installing this plugin it says

Add a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ':quartz-monitor:<plugin version>'
```

I have added

```
compile ':quartz-monitor:1.1'
```

But it is giving Error as:

```
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates :quartz-monitor:1.1, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version>
```

after Digging deep i come to know the plugin repo of grails

http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/quartz-monitor/

where it has a pom file for this plugin as quartz-monitor-1.1.pom

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>quartz-monitor</artifactId>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
  <version>1.1</version>
   ......
```

So, i made changes as adding the groupId from here to my BuildConfig.groovy

now dependencies look like

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz-monitor:1.1'
```

But now i am getting error as

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:quartz-monitor:jar:1.1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

how can i install this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version:

```
compile ":quartz-monitor:1.0"
```

The version 1.1 of quartz-monitor does not exist today (2/Nov/2015). If you open the Grails Plugin Manager, you will see the plugin in the list, if you expand it, you will see all the versions sorted by last to first, and the last is 1.0

[image]